Why is the boiling point of SO3 greater than NH3?
NH3 has a net dipole facing upwards towards the nitrogen atom, meaning that it can undergo hydrogen bonding. It also has dispersion forces.
But SO3 has no net dipole as it has a trigonal planar structure, which means that the only intermolecular force that it has are dispersion forces. I understand that SO3 has a greater molar mass (80g/mol) than NH3 (17g/mol), but would this fully explain the difference in boiling point? Especially considering that there are hydrogen bonds in NH3?
Also just a question if anyone knows comparatively how much smaller is a dispersion force in comparison to dipole dipole/hydrogen bonds.
NOTE: SO3 boiling point is 44.9C while NH3 boiling point is -33.34C

Sulfur_trioxide#Trimer
Both liquid and gaseous $\ce{SO3}$ exists in an equilibrium between the monomer and the cyclic trimer.

$\ce{SO3}$ boiling point is $318 $ K, while $\ce{NH3}$ boils at $240$ K. The difference is only $78$ K = $32$ % of the lowest value. It is surprisingly low, when considering the difference in molar mass :  ($80$ g/mol vs $17$ g/mol). So $80$ is $4.7$ times higher than $17$. $4.7$ times higher !

@Poutnic: I agree with you. Also, according to here, bond order is 1.4 (not traditional 2).
